# Kendo notification widget hide and show multiple times

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm working on a set of CRUD operations and the Kendo notification widget is called at requestEnd. The issue is that I need to set up either

autoHideAfter: 5000, 
or hideOnClick: true

The issue is that if the user attempts multiple CRUD operations within 5 seconds, the message shows only for the first operation. After that, the autoHideAfter: 5 secs takes over and doesn't show anything. The crud operations are going through, but the notification widget doesn't show anything, which is confusing to the end user.

Is there a way to toggle the hide/show to hide and show immediately if the widget is already open? That way a string of messages can be shown one after another to the user...

Something like this, if it's possible:

```
kendoNotification({
                hide: function(e) { this.hide(); },
                show: function (e) {
                    if (!$('.' + e.sender.data)[1]) {
                             //do something 
                    }
                },
               autoHideAfter: 5000, // hideOnClick: true, 
                width: '100%'
            }).data('kendoCustomNotification');

//And using it on 'requestEnd' for a custom dataSource: 

myKendoWidget.hide().show().success({ message: "Specific message" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to remove the existing visible notification messages before showing a new one. Use the `getNotifications` method and remove them from the DOM:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/notification#methods-getNotifications

By the way, the above approach will work if you only have **one** Notification widget **instance**. Currently I suspect that you have many instances, which produce overlapping messages.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/notification/overview#configuration-Position

> The usage of more than one Notification widget instances, which display notifications at the same place on the page, is not recommended because the notifications from the multiple instances will overlap.